# Short and long term effects of an Earth sized planet entering Earth's orbit

Tags: planets, space, hard-science, orbital-mechanics, tidal-forces

In this scenario a Earth analog planet is accidentally pulled into Earth's orbit through the creation of a wormhole. The planet would orbit Earth at about 80,000 miles (128747.52 Km). The planet has the same mass and density as Earth.

I need to know what the short term affects are. What would be the effect of the new planet on us? How would tidal forces affect the oceans and the Earth's surface and our infrastucture? How would the weather patterns be affected? Would things in orbit be affected? Would the affects of the new planet be so desvasting that humanity goes extinct?

I also need to know what the future affects would be. If humanity doesn't go extinct, what would it's civilation look like. How would the enviroment and landscape transform? Would atmosphere be disrupted at all? How would the other planets magnetic field affect technology on Earth if at all. How would Earth's rotation and tilt be affected?

Comment: The Moon is about 238,900 mi from Earth, and it has a profound effect on things like tides. But tides will be the least of concerns as an Earth-sized planet closes in MUCH closer than that. While I don't fulfill the hard science tag, you're going to seriously disrupt the Earth's crust as the planet is gripped by massive close gravity. Volcanos, Earthquakes, and insane tides will likely rapidly render the Earth uninhabitable to advanced life as the crust cracks like a hard boiled egg rolled on the counter.

Comment: The moon orbits earth about 3 times further away than this earth like planet. That along with the fact that the earth is 3.7 times larger than the moon, means that this earth like planet would certainly collide with earth as they accelerate towards each other. If they collided humanity would undoubtedly be wiped from existence, so for this planet to orbit at that distance it would have to have some kind of magic, or extremely advance technology able to hold it there.

Comment: @Mattna - got your math a bit off there.  Earth is 81 times as massive as the moon.  Though I suppose if you're just talking about diameter, it makes sense.  Of particular note, though, would be the fact that this new planet would not orbit Earth, they would both orbit a common gravitational centre.  And because this planet is _well_ within the Moon's orbit, you've got a complicated three-body problem that could eject the Moon or smash it into one of the two planets.

Comment: @jdunlop I meant in terms of diameter. Wouldn't they only orbit each other if the new planet was in motion? if the new planet just appeared from the wormhole surely it wouldn't perfectly orbit a gravitational centre? and the Earth's orbit around the sun would surely not let the two planets orbit each other.

Comment: Too many questions in a single post, and all of them too broad on their own

Comment: @Mattna - I'm assuming that the planet magically arrives on an ideal vector, since it also magically survived a trip through a wormhole and magically arrived inside the moon's orbit without any other negative consequences - until, of course, tidal stresses start.  The point, though, was that the OP said "orbiting the Earth", which it definitely would not be doing; the two would be orbiting a barycentre.

Comment: When the new planet arrives, it may, if sufficient handwaving is applied, with the correct velocity vector to put it nicely in an orbit around the common center of mass with Earth. But Earth itself most certainly does not have such a velocity vector. Kaboom.

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.

Answer (score 8):

Hard-science for something for as many complex interactions as the situation you propose is challenging because we just don't know enough about the earth to be certain of all the effects.

The primary issue is the huge tidal forces Earth-2 would inflict.

Tidal force is proportional to the inverse of 3rd power of the distance. Our moon average about 238,00 miles distance. So Earth2 tidal forces would be roughly (238.9/80)^3 or 26.63 times as great for the same mass. However, the Earth-1 is over 81 times the lunar mass, to the tidal force would be over 26.63 * 81 = 2157 times greater.

Mean deep ocean daily tidal range is about 2 feet. Lunar tides are about twice as strong as solar tides, so the lunar tidal range is about 1.3 feet. The earth-2 tidal range would be about 2800 feet. Tidal ranges at the shoreline are generally greater than deep ocean tidal range, and depend heavily upon the local geography.

However, it would be safe to assume that shore tidal ranges would frequently exceed 3000 feet - i.e., +/- 1500 feet from the nominal value.

Needless to say this would cause extreme flooding. I found a paper describing [global population vs. altitude](https://www.pnas.org/content/95/24/14009) -- the key take-away is that in 1998, roughly 72% of the global population lived within 500 meters of sea level (500 meters = 1640 feet), and 67% within 400 meters (1312 feet), so somewhere around 70% of the population of Earth-1 drowns within the first 12 hours (unless something else kills them first)

Tides affect the sea more than land, but because of the Earth-2, the land tides will be significant. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any data that actually would allow an analysis of the expected results from crustal tidal deformation. However, I did find a reference stating [that crustal deflection can reach 1.1 meters at its peak](http://qdl.scs-inc.us/2ndParty/Pages/9925.html). Given the paucity of information from such a bare statements, I hesitate to conclude too much, except that with Earth-2, I would expect crustal tides to be in the range of dozens to hundreds of meters.

What this means in terms of earthquakes and volcanoes is too hard for me to model, but I would expect it to be significant - and that the problem would grow stronger as progressive damage occurs from unhealed cracks, etc. in earlier cycles. Crustal heating would also further weaken the crust (strength decreases with temperature) - but the amount of crustal heating is not easily and accurately predictable. Certainly in the short term many existing fault lines would be triggered to release their currently stored energy resulting in major earthquakes on most fault-lines.

Lots and lots of bad things for Earth-1 to say the least.

Earth-2 would also be very likely to destabilize the moons orbit. Would be a real shame if this caused it to crash into Earth-1, or even Earth-2. A crash into Earth-2 would doubtless result in enough debris to strike Earth-1 to cause catastrophic atmospheric heating (hundreds to thousands of degrees)

Certainly, civilization as we know it would be destroyed, even a decent chance of killing of nearly all mankind - perhaps enough so that it would not ever recover considering the ongoing survival challenges.

The question is far too broad to meet the requirements, but I thought a hint of the destruction meted out could still be useful.